# Pandas - grouping IDs of each repeatable class and putting them in a list in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I feel like this is a simply question, but I do not use pandas that often.
Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
d = {'repeat': [23, 25,23], 'unique': [1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

How do I obtain, using pandas built-in function a dataframe of this form:

```
grouped = {'unique': [[1,3],[2]], 'repeat': [23,25]}
dg =pd.DataFrame(data=grouped)
```

df -- pandas built-in operations --> dg?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `groupby` and `agg`:

```
df.groupby("repeat").agg(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index()
```